# Edit a register with a form upload field

Tags: php, file-upload, cakephp-2.0

I have an app that I create an register with an file upload. Ok, the file upload and the created register it's fine.

I want that when the user put a file, it will do the update. If not, do not update of the field containing the file path.

But, I need to edit this register. When edditing, my file upload show an error:

**Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'**
SQL Query: UPDATE `societario`.`attorneys` SET `nome` = 'teste editar', `empresa` = '', `filial` = '', `unidade` = 'Energia', `alcada` = 'Até 10.000', `validade` = '123123111', `arquivo` = Array WHERE `societario`.`attorneys`.`id` = '83'

My create controller:

```
if($this->request->is('post')){

$targetFolder = 'societario/app/webroot/uploads/'; // Relative to the root
$tempFile = $this->request->data['Attorney']['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
$targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $this->request->data['Attorney']['arquivo']['name'];;
        move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);


        $this->Attorney->saveAll($this->request->data, array('fieldList' => array('nome','empresa','filial','unidade','validade', 'alcada', 'status')));
        $this->Attorney->updateAll(
array('arquivo' => "'".$this->request->data['Attorney']['arquivo']['name'] ."'",),
array('id' => $this->Attorney->id));
```

My edit controller:

**EDIT: MODIFIED THE EDIT CONTROLLER. THE SOLUTION IS IN AN ANSWER THAT FOLLOWS.**

```
    $this->Attorney->id = $id;
    $this->set('poderes',$this->Attorney->Power->find('list', array('fields' => 'resumo')));

         if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            $this->request->data = $this->Attorney->read();
        } else {

            if ($this->Attorney->save($this->request->data)) {


            $this->Session->setFlash('Usuário editado com sucesso!', 'default', array('class' => 'flash_sucess'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'usuarios'));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->request->data['Attorney']['arquivo']['name'])` show?

Comment: need this on create or edit?

Comment: Well, since the error message you're getting is on the UPDATE....

Comment: Sorry. nothing is returning

Comment: `var_dump` will always print something - if the variable is empty, it'll show you that; otherwise it'll print out the contents.

Comment: I fond the answer !!thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!! thanks

My edit controller:

```
$this->Attorney->id = $id;
    $this->set('poderes',$this->Attorney->Power->find('list', array('fields' => 'resumo')));

         if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            $this->request->data = $this->Attorney->read();

        } else {

            if ($this->Attorney->save($this->request->data, array('fieldList' => array('nome','empresa','filial','unidade','validade', 'alcada', 'status')))) {

            if(!empty($this->request->data['Attorney']['arquivo']['name'])) {

                $targetFolder = 'societario/app/webroot/uploads/'; // Relative to the root
                $tempFile = $this->request->data['Attorney']['arquivo']['tmp_name'];
                $targetPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder;
                $targetFile = rtrim($targetPath,'/') . '/' . $this->request->data['Attorney']['arquivo']['name'];;
                move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile);

                $this->Attorney->updateAll(
                array('arquivo' => "'".$this->request->data['Attorney']['arquivo']['name'] ."'",),
                array('id' => $this->Attorney->id));
                $this->Session->setFlash('procuração editada com sucesso!', 'default', array('class' => 'flash_sucess'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'usuarios'));
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash('Usuário editado com sucesso!', 'default', array('class' => 'flash_sucess'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'usuarios'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arquivo = Array
```

It thinks Array is a field...  So if you literally want "Array" saved then put it in single quotes.  Otherwise I think you forgot the $.

EDIT - Thought I'd mention that this is in your UPDATE statement.

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks